# What is the release version for widgets documented in https://api.flutter.dev? e.g. where is AnimatedGrid?

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's take the case of [AnimatedGrid](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedGrid-class.html), which is available in the file `animated_scroll_view.dart` of master branch in
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets.

Yet, it is not available in the latest (as of today) Flutter release 3.1.10 here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/3.3.10/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets. Hence, the sample program from documentation not even compile.

I cannot find either in API docs which version provides the `AnimatedGrid`?

Comment: I navigate to this page : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/7523ab5cc1554cbeeb043345759a0909e3834f48

Comment: and I found that the lowest version with animated grid is `3.5.0-4.0.pre`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to find out when a feature/widget was first released i usually would go to [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/) and find the page for that widget.

Let's take the example of the **[SelectionArea](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectionArea-class.html)** widget which was released in Flutter 3.3 as we know from [this post](https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-3-3-893c7b9af1ff).

So, in flutter.dev I click on the little *file icon* as shown below:

[image]

That will take us to the file in **Github** where that widget is defined. There look for the line defining the Widget and click on its line-number to open a context menu and click on "View git blame":

[image]

there you will find the commit that made the last change on that line. If between the comit description and the file there is an icon like this

[image]

click on it until you travel to the first commit that introduced that class/line. Click on that comit's description, in our case would be as follows:

[image]

there you will see the last and the first Flutter version to contain that change with three dots in between that will show all the versions between the first and the last version that contain that change:

[image]

Look for the first version where no "pre" suffix is present. That will be the release version (3.3 in our case)

[image]

### What if the file-icon in flutter.dev does not redirect to a valid github page?

Well, i believe that means there is not yet a release for that widget, as is the case for **AnimatedGrid** where we get this:

[image]

In that case you still can find some information. Go to flutter/flutter in **Github** and search for **AnimatedGrid** in that repository

[image]

there you can view the commits that contain AnimatedGrid and look for the oldest, in the case of AnimatedGrid, as of today there is only one commit that contains that word. Click on it and you will again see all the versions that include changes on that file

[image]

there we can see that there is not yet a final release for that widget (al releases have the "pre" suffix!).